# Unable to play audio file (.mp3) in Android through Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-audiomanager

I am trying to develop an android application which can play audio files, through Phonegap framework.

Below is the code for that, which is not the index.html, but another HTML page in the project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
       <title>A New App Try</title>

          <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        -->

    <script src="/android_asset/www/js/corodova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/android_asset/www/css/MyownTry.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script src="/android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/android_asset/www/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  //Wait for PhoneGap to load

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        /*
        function onDeviceReady() {
            playAudio("../assets/files/Roja_Flute.mp3");
        }

        */
        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

            if (!playing) {
                my_media.play(); 
                document.getElementById('play').src = "/android_asset/www/img/pause_icon.jpg";
                playing = true; 

              } else {
                my_media.pause();
                document.getElementById('play').src = "/android_asset/www/img/Playicon.png";    
                playing = false; 
              }


        }

        // Pause audio
        // 
       /* function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }*/

        // Stop audio
        // 
        function stopAudio() {
            my_media.stop();
             playing = false;
              document.getElementById('play').src = "/android_asset/www/img/Playicon.png";}

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback 
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        // 
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }

         </script>



<style> 
img{
width=30%;

}
</style>  </head>
    <body>


<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/files/Roja_Flute.mp3');"><img id="play" src="/android_asset/www/img/Playicon.png"/></a>
<!-- <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();"><img id="pause"src="/android_asset/www/img/pause_icon.jpg" width="20%"/></a> -->
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();"><img id="stop" src="/android_asset/www/img/stop_icon.jpg" /></a>
   <!--     <p id="audio_position"></p>-->


<br/><br/>
<a href="index.html">Go back to Home Page</a>

<div data-role="footer">
    <p>Copyright 2013 | Mani C | newtolearn.android</p>
</div>
      </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting icons to be smaller ones, as I have defined in the style element, for 30% of image size. And, I am expecting when I click on the Play icon, the audio file to be played.

Unfortunately both the expected behaviors are not occuring. I am seeing a larger 'Play icon', smaller 'Stop icon' and getting, 'Uncaught Reference Exception: variable playAudio is undefined in index.html'(when in fact, the above HTML code has nothing to do with index.html).

Can somebody, please help and can possibly provide a workaround code..?

Thanks in advance!

Mani